# Get Custom Taxonomy ID within loop

Tags: custom-post-types, php, custom-taxonomy

I can't figure how to get the ID of the custom taxonomy I'm using to loop through the custom post type called "test_values".

```
function prefix_load_term_posts () {
    $term_slug = $_POST[ 'term' ];
    $args = array (
             'post_type' => 'test_values',
             'posts_per_page' => 1,
             'tax_query' => array(
              array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'test_value_category',
                    'field'    => 'slug',
                    'terms'    => $term_slug ,
               ),

              ),
         );

    global $post;

    $myposts = get_posts( $args );
    ob_start ();

    foreach( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); ?>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Anyone have any suggestions how to get this taxonomy ID within the loop?

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by

Comment: @inarilo I'm a little confused how to use that in this particular context?

Comment: use the slug to get the taxonomy details. you don't need the loop for that.

Comment: or maybe i didn't understand your question

Comment: Yeah so I'm trying to get the ID for the custom taxonomy which is $post. When I echo `$post->term_id' within the foreach loop, nothing shows up...

Comment: $myposts contains posts not taxonomies

Comment: right apologies should have worded that better. $myposts are posts with a custom taxonomy. I am trying to get the ID of that custom taxonomy

Comment: just use the function i linked

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this function `get_term_by($field, $value, $taxonomy, $output, $filter )`   or

```
$termID = [];
$terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'taxonomy');
foreach ($terms as $term) {
    $termID[] = $term->term_id;
}
```

or `get_queried_object_id()`

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, what I had was way to complicated. Here's what I ended up doing that worked:

```
<?php $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'newsroom_post_category' ); 
                foreach($terms as $term) {
                    $termlinks = get_term_link($term);
                        echo '<p class="post-content--cat">';
                            echo '<a href="' . $termlinks . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';  
                        echo '</p>'; }?>
```

This got all the Taxonomy terms attributed to the custom post.